# How to modify A* algorithm in order to find the minimum energy path between 2 points?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, energy

If I have an array of 3 dimensional points, how can I modify the cost function in the A* algorithm in order to find the minimum energy path from point A to point B? Originally the algorithm uses Euclidean distance + the heuristics to decide which of the neighboring points to consider first. I couldn't find any useful resource, neighter on the physics side.

Comment: Maybe [this post at gamedev stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150605/how-to-adapt-pathfinding-algorithms-to-restricted-movement) is exactly the kickstart you are looking for?
Focusing on A*, you may calculate the cost of the action based on the energy cost. A* may not be the best approach for that, but I have seen implementation that considers, for example, the terrain heightmap (slopeness) or the terrain type (mud, grass...). let me know if this makes sense? :)

Comment: What does "minimum energy path" mean?  If you have the energies defined as edge-weights on a graph, as well as some admissible heuristic _(which could be as simple as Euclidean distance, depending on what "energy" means)_, then A\* should work fine as-is.

Comment: @diogoslima that's what I'm looking for. I have the map of a mountain, (x, y, z) coordinates but I don't know what is the energy needet to travel from point A to point B

Comment: Hey @BalogSzilárd, a simple approach is to update the [A* heuristic](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html) to add the steepness to the weight. Here is [another post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89824/how-can-i-compute-a-steepness-value-for-height-map-cells) about steepness. For the type of terrain, one of many options is having metadata associated with each node, almost like a [texture splat map](https://nickelcitypixels.com/blog/2016/01/19/whats-a-splat-map/). If this makes sense I will write a full answer next.

Comment: @diogoslima I've calculated that the only thing that matters is the height difference between two states. That would change the cost function. Unfortunately I haven't heard about texture splat map.

Comment: The sum of all the height differences will be the same for all paths, equal to the difference in height between the two points.  Does that mean that all paths have the same energy?  If not, then please define "minimum energy".  Your question doesnt' make sense without that definition.

Comment: Energy is the phisical meaning of energy.

Comment: Hi @BalogSzilárd, I must say you got me confused, hehe. So, you already know how to calculate the cost, and you already have a set description of the nodes (positions in 3d space). The specific question you have is how to update a certain implementation of the A* algorithm? Could you link to the code, or update the question to at least show the portion of code that is challenging you?

Comment: Hi @diogoslima, the thing is, I don't really know whether my calculation is correct or not. I think I know how the A* algorithm works and the only thing I need is to change the G cost of the function. My real question is whether or not my calculation for the energy needed is correct or not.

Comment: But @BalogSzilárd, and I hope others join the discussion, the minimum energy cost relates to the environment and variables you are simulating. So, if your data is just a grid of vertexes 3d positions, the height is all you got. Now, if you have more data, like the materials, you can use it. Take a look at [this thesis](https://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~zwood/research/students/ATsui_thesis.pdf), you will see images showing how the energy cost is used, notice that how the energy cost is calculated is indifferent to the A* algorithm, it just changes the weight. Hmm, maybe I should write an answer?

Comment: @doigoslima in this case, there's no variation in materials, only height, I should probably edit the question, I need the formula to calculate weight only, not the actual algorithm